# Probability of a random variable with sequence.

Tags: probability-theory, borel-cantelli-lemmas

I want to show

$P\{[Y_n > k_n] i.o.]\} = 0 $ iff $\sum_n P[Y_1 > k_n] < \infty$

And

$P\{[Y_n > k_n] i.o.]\} = 1 $ iff $\sum_n P[Y_1 > k_n] = \infty$

Where $Y_n$, $n \ge 1$ are independent and identically distributed random variables and $k_n$ is a sequence of constants.

I tried using the Borel Zero-One Law, but I'm confused where the iff statements come from.

Comment: "I'm confused where the iff statements come from" Which implications were you able to show?

Comment: I can prove it up to $Y_1 > k_n$. I don't see why $Y_1$ works.

Comment: ?? Sorry, the meaning of your message is undecipherable. Perhaps you forgot that every $Y_n$ has the same distribution hence $P(Y_n>k_n)=P(Y_1>k_n)$ for every $n$?

Comment: I completely forgot the iid portion. So this is just a direct result of the Borel Zero-One law. Thanks for the help.